# Drawing a simple Graph from a table

Tags: java, graph

I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fractal.walkers.DrawingPanel.myPaint(DrawingPanel.java:65)
at com.fractal.walkers.MainClass$2.actionPerformed(MainClass.java:1256)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

.
.
.

It appears the tmp is initializing but my DrawingPanel cannot see the new value. I am a beginner trying to learn with trial and error.I am struggling with this for over a week. Help is appreciated.

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

JFrame frame;
 JPanel pane;
 JTable table;
DefaultTableModel model;
ArrayList<Object> arrX;
ArrayList<Object> arrY;
JButton button;
JButton button2;

Integer [][] tmp;
Integer[] xAxis;
Integer[] yAxis;

ListIterator i;
int x1=0;
int y1=0;
int x2 = 0;
int y2= 0;
Thread thread;
JScrollPane scrollPane;

public void framesetter(){

 pane = new JPanel();
 button = new JButton();
 button2 = new JButton();
 scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
 frame = new JFrame();
 table = new JTable();
 DrawingPanel drawpane = new DrawingPanel();
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setSize(1280,800);
 arrX  = new ArrayList<Object>();
    arrY = new ArrayList<Object>();


 table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {                                            
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "X Axis", "Y Axis"
            }

         ));

 pane.setLayout(null);
 frame.setLayout(null);
 scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

 scrollPane.setSize(180,220);
 scrollPane.setLocation(10, 10);
 button.setSize(100,50);
 button.setLocation(50,250);
 button2.setSize(100,50);
 button2.setText("DRAW");
 button2.setLocation(50,500);

 pane.setLocation(1050,10 );
 pane.setSize(200, 780);
 pane.add(scrollPane);
 pane.add(button);
 pane.add(button2);

 drawpane.setLocation(10, 10);
 drawpane.setSize(1040, 780);
 frame.add(drawpane);

 frame.add(pane);
 frame.setVisible(true);

 model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

try
{
   jbInit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        drawpane.decide = true; 

        drawpane.repaint();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        i = arrX.listIterator();
        if(model.getValueAt(0, 0)!=null){

        for(int x = 0; x<model.getRowCount();x++){

            if(model.getValueAt(x, 0)!=null){
            arrX.add(model.getValueAt(x, 0));
            arrY.add(model.getValueAt(x, 1));

            if(x+1 == model.getRowCount()){
                arrX.add(model.getValueAt(x, 0));
                arrY.add(model.getValueAt(x, 1));

            }

            }
        }

    for(int y= 0 ; y<arrX.size()-1;y++){

         x1 = Integer.valueOf((String) arrX.get(y));
         y1 = Integer.valueOf((String) arrY.get(y));
     x2 = Integer.valueOf((String) arrX.get(y+1));
     y2 = Integer.valueOf((String) arrY.get(y+1));

        System.out.println(x1 + "  "+  y1 + "  "+x2+"   "+ arrX.size());

    }

     xAxis  = new Integer[arrX.size()];
      yAxis  = new Integer[arrY.size()];

     for(int xS = 0; xS<arrX.size();xS++){
         xAxis[xS] = (Integer.valueOf((String) arrX.get(xS)));
    ;    
     }
         for(int yS = 0; yS<arrY.size();yS++){
             yAxis[yS] = (Integer.valueOf((String) arrY.get(yS)));
            }
             tmp = new Integer [arrX.size()][arrY.size()];

             for(int xS = 0 ; xS<arrX.size();xS++){

                 for(int yS = 0 ; yS<2;yS++){
                     if(yS == 0){
                         tmp[xS][yS] =xAxis [xS]; 

                     }
                     else {tmp[xS][yS] =yAxis [xS];}

                     System.out.println("tmp "+"["+xS+"]" +"["+yS+"]=  "+     tmp[xS][yS]);


                 }

             }


    }

}

});

}



public Integer recharge(int a , int b){

this.tmp[a][b]= tmp[a][b];

return tmp[a][b];
}


private void jbInit() throws Exception
   {





   // This is the line that does all the magic!
   ExcelAdapter myAd = new ExcelAdapter(table);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainClass f = new MainClass();
    f.framesetter();

}

}
```

This is the drawing class:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{

Boolean decide = false;


MainClass f = new MainClass();
int x, y;


public DrawingPanel(){      

}
public void paintBorder(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 1000, 700);        

    }

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2d;

    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.drawLine(500, 0, 500, 700);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 350, 1000, 350);        
     if (decide) {
        myPaint(g2d);       
     }  

    }

private void myPaint(Graphics g2d) {


    Integer value = new Integer(f.tmp.length);


    if(value != null && value != 0){

  for(int xS = 0; xS<f.tmp.length;xS++){
      g2d.drawLine(f.tmp[xS][0],f.tmp[xS][1],f.tmp[xS+1]    [0],f.tmp[xS+1][1]);  

  }

    }


    decide = false;


  }





}
```

I think it is something to do with the decide boolean being false and true. How can I initialize variables or pass Array into the drawing function. Thank you.

jbinit is for pasting values from Excel tables. Works fine.

Comment: See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I read the article. I am still confused a bit. My system.out prints tmp array correctly. Though my Draw class sees it null. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: I can use x1, x2,y1,y2 variables without a problem. But accessing arrays is a big no no. also arrX and arrY are unaccessible too.